# Tag Rename Request: FIFA games

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

*FIFA* games are **not** *FIFA 20xx*, they are simply *FIFA xx*.  Therefore:

- [fifa-2008](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fifa-2008) → [fifa-08](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fifa-08)
- apparently nobobdy likes *FIFA 09*
- [fifa-2010](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fifa-2010) → [fifa-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fifa-10)
- [fifa-2011](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fifa-2011) → [fifa-11](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fifa-11)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
updating post history, 2/10/18 rows affected
updating posts, 1/5/15 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 1/5/15 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1/1/1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1/1/1 rows affected
tag remapping of [fifa-08/10/11] and [fifa-2008/2010/2011] complete!
remapping 0/0/0 synonyms
Tag Synonym fifa-2008/2010/2011 -> fifa-08/10/11 was approved!
```

♪

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. I was going to tag my question [tag:fifa-12], but didn't because there was no [tag:fifa-11], just a [tag:fifa-2011], and I did not want to break the naming convention here.